# JQuery click listener for class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class of images in HTML, with IDs `img1`,`img2`,...,`img9`. I want to make links (HTML `a` tag) with IDs `link_img1`, `link_img2`, ..., `link_img9` so that whenever I click on a link, the corresponding image appears.

I'm thinking about assigning all the links to the same class, then add a JQuery click listener for that class, and inside the listener, look for the ID of that link, and shows the corresponding image. How do I add a JQuery listener for a *class*, and how do I get the ID from the element?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you can. What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited to make it more specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't use the ids of `a` tags to define their target.
Better use the `href` attribute instead:

```
<img id="img1" ...>
<img id="img2" ...>
<a href="#img1" class="image-link">Click me</a>
<a href="#img2" class="image-link">Click me</a>

jQuery("a.image-link").click(function(){
  $(this.href).show();
});
```

This allows you to have two links for the same image.

Comment: What's the reason behind using `jQuery` instead of `$` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('a.yourClassName').click(function(){
   $('img#'+ this.id).show();         
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a listener for a class, just select it the jQuery way (i.e. $('elem.class').  Then use attr() to get the id.

Answer (score 2):

Here. As mentioned in some other answers, `id` is probably not the best way to determine what action you should take. Use another attribute as you see fit

```
$('a.some-class').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'one':
          // do something
          break;
        case 'two':
          // do something
          break;
        default:
          // do something
          break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('a.yourClass').click(function(){
    var $linkID= $(this).attr('id'); 
    $('img#'+ $linkID).show();         
});
```